# Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t = 0

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, approximation

I am trying to compare an approximation formula for a particular nonlinear ODE with different right hand sides. The code I use is:

```
sol = NDSolve[{w''[t] + Exp[w[t]] == Sin[t], w[0] == 0, 
w'[0] == 0}, w, {t, 0, 10}, Method->"StifnessSwitching"];
wsol[t_] := Evaluate[w[t] /. sol]
wBlue[s_, t_] := 
 1/s NIntegrate[
   Log[1 - Tanh[(t - t1)/Sqrt[2]]^2] Sin[t1], {t1, 0, t}]
```

However, NDSolve gives

```
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
```

I guess it is because of the right hand side f[t]. Is there any way to get rid of this and plot wsol and wBlue against t?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You miss typed `"StiffnessSwitching"` - but you do not need that in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! There was a minor typo, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to correct the definition f[t]:

```
f[t_] := Sin[t]

sol = NDSolve[{w''[t] + Exp[w[t]] == f[t], w[0] == 0, w'[0] == 0},w, {t, 0,10}]
(* {{w -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>]}} *)
```

Comment: It was a typo in the code. The NDSolve still gives the same error. I tried several built in methods like BDF, MethodOfLines, ExplicitRungeKutta, etc.

Comment: Before(!) you execute NDSolve f[t] must be defined. Otherwise NDSolve gives the error NDSolve::ndnum:

Comment: Dear Ulrich, I have already fixed that issue.

Comment: `f[t_] := Sin[t]` should be the first line in your code. If so your code run's without error warning!

Comment: Can you run it successfully on your machine? I get the same error even when I write Sin[t] directly in the NDSolve.

Comment: Just look at my answer. Runs without error...